# duplicated key of id in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This code won't work, I got error of `E11000 duplicate key error index error`.

```
Student.update({_id: id, 'data.date':date}, {'$set': {'data.score': 50}}, {upsert: true}, 
    function(err,result) {
        res.json(1);
  });
```

I have no clue how to solve it when I can do

```
  Student.findOne({_id: id}, function(err,result){
          res.json(result)
        })
```

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400195/duplicated-key-of-id-in-mongodb/41400670#41400670) below help you? If so then you can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible problems:

1. You may have set some of the fields as unique and Mongo created an index for that field. For example if `data.score` would be unique then you couldn't have two documents with the same value and maybe other document already has a value of 50.

The solution would be to search for indexes and remove the ones that you don't want.

2. Maybe your search for `{_id: id, 'data.date': date}` doesn't return a result but not because you don't have a document with that id, but because it doesn't have that 'data.date' field that you search for. Then the upsert tries to insert a new document (because the search didn't find anything that has both '_id' equal to `id` and 'data.date' equal to `date`) but it fails to do so (because you already have a document with '_id' equal to `id`).

The solution would be to search only by `_id` if you're using `upsert`.